# Android listview with header view not getting the correct item position

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem with my listview. I added a header view by using

```
listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

and it's working. I use this to prevent header view from being counted in the list item. This header view has expand/collapse icon. So initially, header view is collapsed and it's only viewing a truncated text by ellipsis. When expand icon is clicked it should expand (I already have coded the expand/collapse animation).

This is what I've tried:

**MainActivity**

```
episodesAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, this, itemList);
listView.setAdapter(episodesAdapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void   onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

if (commentView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
episodesAdapter.setItemSelected(position);
Log.e(TAG, "LV POS: " + position);
TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvListTitle);
TextView details = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDetails);
setDetails(title.getText().toString(), details.getText().toString());

} });
```

Selected item from list is displayed in the header view (details).

**CustomAdapter**

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int position) {

    if(data.get(position) != null) {
        return data.get(position);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    try {
        if (convertView == null) {

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_video_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(); 
            viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            viewHolder.tvDetails = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvListDetails);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        result = new HashMap<>();
        result = data.get(position);
        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(result.get(Constants.TITLE));
     viewHolder.tvDetails.setText(result.get(Constants.DESCRIPTION));

        if(mItemSelected == position){
            convertView.setSelected(true);
            activity.setDetails(result.get(Constants.TITLE), result.get(Constants.DESCRIPTION) );
        }
        else {
            convertView.setSelected(false);
        }


    } catch (Exception e ) {
    }

    return convertView;

}



private int mItemSelected = 0;

public void setItemSelected(int position){
    mItemSelected = position;
}
```

FYI, I set my listview as SINGLE_CHOICE, to make selected item highlighted. But I have a problem with getting the correct item position, my first item becomes 1 instead of 0. And when I expand my header view, it replaces the selected item (first/default item) to the next item (2nd item from the list) and when I collapse my header view, it goes back to the originally selected item. What seems to be the issue in here? I'm stuck with this problem for weeks. And I couldn't proceed. I would really appreciate any kind of help. Thanks!

Header View:

```
 <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlHolder"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:background="@color/main_blue"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDetails"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/lAdditionalView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvDetails"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:text="Cast"
            android:id="@+id/tvCastHolder"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCasts"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Genre"
            android:id="@+id/tvGenreHolder"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvGenres"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Views"
            android:id="@+id/tvViewsHolder"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvViews"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivArrow"
        android:src="@drawable/chatarrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lAdditionalView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post the layout for your header view?

Comment: @AlexTownsend sure check my updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a header view to a `ListView` using `addHeaderView()` it offsets the position of all of your items in the list by the number of header views you have added.

In your `OnItemClickListener` change your `episodesAdapter.setItemSelected(position)` to `episodesAdapter.setItemSelected(position - listView.getHeaderViewsCount)`. This will correct the offset and set the selected position to the selected view correctly.

Comment: Thanks! It's solved now. Btw, I have another question posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35452834/android-listview-with-expandable-collapsible-header-animation-issue. Maybe you can help me.